# Android BLE get connected but do not get any callback at BluetoothGattCallback()

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Arduino code driven ESP32 chip.
For Android code, it setup a callback for connection attempt

```
mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE );
```

but

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback()
```

do not happen.

However, from Arduino side, it does see a connected happen and start to send data out.  ESP32 also blink connected LED.

Any idea what was wrong?

SDK version is 26,

minSDK is 23,

targetSDK is 23,

run on Samsung Galaxy S7

thanks a lot!

```
    @TargetApi(21)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;
    private TextView line_1, line_2, line_3, line_4;
    private ImageButton btnTrash, btnEmail;
    private UUID uuid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uuid = UUID.fromString("8dc99748-0ad4-11e8-ba89-0ed5f89f718b");
        line_1              = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLine1);
        line_2              = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLine2);
        line_3              = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLine3);
        line_4              = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLine4);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    }

private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        line_3.setText("" + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                line_1.setText(" connected ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," connected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //  gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        line_1.setText(" server discover");
        gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get
                (0));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                             characteristic, int status) {
        Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
        gatt.disconnect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
    {
        line_1.setText(" charactertics changed");
    }
};
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            }
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            scanLeDevice(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mGatt.close();
        mGatt = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Bluetooth not enabled.
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                     //   mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                line_1.setText(" mLEScanner ");
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            line_2.setText("try connect to " + btDevice.getName());
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                line_2.setText(" batch scan result");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            line_2.setText("scan fail");
        }
    };

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            connectToDevice(device);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            try {
                BluetoothSocket temp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback, TRANSPORT_LE );
            } catch( Exception e)
            {

            }

            line_3.setText( device.getAddress());
            line_4.setText( "device type: "+ device.getType());
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't do UI stuff in the GATT callbacks. You need to post the work to the UI thread.